# Как перевести сайт из intellij idea в рабочее состояние на хостинг?

Tags: windows, intellij-idea, maven, веб-сервер, build

Как перевести сайт из `intellij idea` в рабочее состояние на хостинг?

Написал контроллер сайта в `intellij idea` на `maven`, есть несколько темплейтов, картинки и `css`, в самой среде все прекрасно работает, но вот когда я нажимаю `package` генерится файл или без темплейтов или без картинок и `css`, при запуске отображается не корректно.

Как это все перевести в рабочее состояние, чтобы залить на хостинг и в каком виде это вообще все должно быть там?
Есть ли вообще возможность заливать на хостинг `jar` файл в качестве сайта? 
Если нет, то какие есть другие варианты?

Answer (score 0):

По вашему ответу, я так понимаю, что вы написали сервлет и какие-то базовые элементы по `html` и `css`.

Если вопрос в том как запустить web-проект, то ответ будет таким, что необходимо установить какой-нибудь веб-контейнер, самым простым является `TomCat`, в него, а точнее в папку, куда он установлен необходимо поместить war-файл, который формируется благодаря `Maven => package`.

Если формирование war-файла непроисходит, стоит проверить такие вещи как: конфигурация в `web.xml` файле, а так же `pom.xml`. Так же должен быть грамотно написан сервлет, а именно наследоваться от `HttpServlet`.

Рекомендую к прочтению: [Ссылка №1](https://devcolibri.com/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-servlet-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE/) , [Ссылка №2](https://metanit.com/java/javaee/1.1.php)

Если более конкретно, то задавайте детально вопрос и больше каких-то факторов за которые можно зацепиться.